# GET and POST requests in testing/ Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

Guy, I need your help. Since I'm newbie and I'm making my first app in Django I came to an issue while testing my app. There is problem with testing views, and since tested manually everything works fine problem occurs while testing automatition.

I think the issue may be related to POST / GET requests because I made things in way that, most things are based on GET, even those which change things in DB. POST request is reserved only to forms. When I start tests, every action that is made seems lacking-effect like those GET requests don't work.

Ok here comes the code:

Views:

```
@login_required
def new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        player = Player.objects.get(name=request.user)
        hosted = Game(host=player.nick)
        form = CreateGame(instance=hosted, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("home", name="new_room")


@login_required
def delete_room(request, id):
    game = Game.objects.get(id=id)
    player = Player.objects.get(name=request.user)
    if player.nick == game.host and game.how_many_players_ready == 0:
        if not game.is_played:
            game.delete()
            return redirect("home", name="game_deleted")
        else:
            return redirect('detail', id=game.id)
    else:
        return redirect('detail', id=game.id)
```

Tests:

```
class TestViews(TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser', password='12345')
    self.user2 = User.objects.create_user(username='testuser2', password='12345')
    usr = self.user
    self.client.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
    self.player = Player.objects.create(name=usr, parent = usr.username, nick = 'nie')

def test_create_many_rooms(self):
    #this one works -> POST
    self.new_room=reverse('new_room')
    self.client.post(self.new_room, {'name' :'mariaczi', 'host':'mario'})
    self.client.post(self.new_room, {'name': 'mariaczi2','host':'mario'})
    self.client.post(self.new_room, {'name': 'mariaczi3', 'host': 'mario'})
    suma = Game.objects.all().count()

    self.assertEquals(suma,3)

def test_host_delete_empty_room(self):
    #this one not
    game = Game.objects.create(name='empty', host='testuser', is_played=False, max_players=4)
    self.delete_room = reverse('delete_gam', args=[game.id])
    self.client.get(self.delete_room, follow=True)
    suma = Game.objects.all().count()

    self.assertEquals(suma,0)
```

OUTCOME: ======================================================================

```
FAIL: test_host_delete_empty_room (game.tests.test_views.TestViews)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dottore/PycharmProjects/Nowa_gra/Nova_gra/game/tests/test_views.py", line 53, in test_host_delete_empty_room
    self.assertEquals(suma,0)
AssertionError: 1 != 0
```

Models:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    is_played = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    max_players = models.IntegerField(default=4)
    who_is_ready = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name="guys_ready", blank=True)
    who_is_playing = models.ManyToManyField(Player, related_name="guys_playing", blank=True)
    turn = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    turn_of_player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='czyja_tura', blank=True, null=True)

   @property
def how_many_players_ready(self):
    return self.who_is_ready.count()

@property
def how_many_players_playing(self):
    return self.who_is_playing.count()

@property
def players_ready(self):
    return list(self.who_is_ready.all())

@property
def players_playing(self):
    return list(self.who_is_playing.all())

@property
def players_playing_str(self):
    res = [i.nick for i in self.who_is_playing.all()]
    return res

@property
def first_player(self):
    return self.players_playing[0]

@property
def second_player(self):
    return self.players_playing[1]

@property
def third_player(self):
    return self.players_playing[2]

@property
def forth_player(self):
    return self.players_playing[3]


@property
def next_player(self):
    x = self.players_playing.index(self.turn_of_player)
    nast= x+1
    if nast > (self.how_many_players_playing - 1):
        self.turn +=1
        self.save()
        return self.players_playing[0]
    else:
        return self.players_playing[x+1]

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Where is the TRICK? Shall I always handle things with database changes other way then generating GET?

Comment: Is `game.how_many_players_ready == 0` condition correct for your test setup? Can you add print statements in delete view to understand what is wrong?

Comment: @DenizKaplan done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trick here... I think the Game object is not getting delete, your `delete_room` has many if-else's. Common debugging technique is to put a print statement in each if else condition to see which path it's taking.

My suspicion is on first part of this if condition,

```
if player.nick == game.host this will result in "nie" == "testuser"
```

which are not equal. But find it yourself using print statements.